# Consulta com jpa + hibernate com mais de um idt na cláusula

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

com hibernate eu posso fazer uma consulta por idt da seguinte forma:

```
entityManager.find(Empresa.class, idtEmpresa);
```

E isso já retornaria o objeto mapeado da classe empresa, mas e se eu quisesse consultar mais de um idt, como ficaria ?

por exemplo, se eu passase um String:

```
String idtEmpresa = "1,2,3";
```

A pergunta é, Como faço uma consulta com vários idts ?

Answer (score 0):

O Hibernate 5 ou superior possui suporte a *multi-load*:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);    
MultiIdentifierLoadAccess<PersonEntity> multiLoadAccess = session.byMultipleIds(Empresa.class);
List<Empresa> empresas = multiLoadAccess.multiLoad(1, 2, 3);
```

Para maiores detalhes e outras opções de uma olhada em [*Thoughts on Java - How to fetch multiple entities by id with Hibernate 5*](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/fetch-multiple-entities-id-hibernate/)